# TypeError: React.createContext is not a function with ApolloContext and Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, graphql, next.js, apollo

I'm trying to test out some typescript code with jest for my TS+NextJS app where I am using apollo+graphql. Unfornautley, I am getting the error

```
TypeError: React.createContext is not a function
```

From the following node module:

`getApolloContext (node_modules/@apollo/client/react/context/ApolloContext.js:7:25)`

When I looked at this error on other questions on Stack Overflow, it says that the react version is outdated, but my react version in my package.json is

`"react": "^17.0.1",`

So I'm not sure what could be causing this issue. It seems like for some reason either the type check is failing or an old version of react is being used in that node module instead of the project-wide one which doesn't seem right.

What I've tried so far is:

Updating my react and react-dom node modules (does nothing)

Pretty stuck at what to do beyond that.

code is here:

`test.tsx`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import DonePage from '../pages/done'

describe('Pages', () => {
  describe('Index', () => {
    it('Pages render', function testCases() {
        render(<DonePage apolloClient={{}} apolloState={{}}/>)
    })
  })
})

export {}
```

`page.tsx`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { withApollo } from 'apollo'
{...}

const DonePage: NextPage<{}> = () => {
  return (
    <>
        {...}
    </>
  )
}

export default withApollo(DonePage, { ssr: false })
```

Where `withApollo` is the code in https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/5089

I'm running the tests with `jest --runInBand`

Comment: Hey, did u get an answer for this?